# Left join in doctrine orm Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have this query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydb.users
left join mydb.jobs
on users.user_id = jobs.job_id;
```

And I used to convert them in orm query just like below:

```
  return 
  $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
  $qb->select('rb', 'l')
     ->from('Admin\Entity\Users', 'rb')
     ->leftJoin(
        'Admin\Entity\Jobs',
        'l',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
        'rb.user_id = l.job_id'
       )
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

But it doesn's still work. I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on null`

please help i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$entityManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
```

Or make sure $this->entityManager is assigned.

Comment: Hello Thanks. I add what u said. And now I get this following error: `Call to a member function get() on null`. What should I do?

Comment: Where do you call this method? In the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Well it simply means you don't have an `EntityManager` instance in `$this->entityManager`.

My guess would be that `$this->entityManager` is probably null because you did not inject an `EntityManager` inside your class instance.

Comment: Hi thanks. I did what you said and now I get error: `Call to a member function get() on null`. what should I do?

Comment: @cyyx what class are you working in? Can you show or tell something about the context

Comment: @cyyx Hello? Anybody there?